# Find a normal vector $n$ to the plane $z−8(x−6)=2(3−y)$.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

To find the normal vector, I need $ax+by+cz=d$ but with this question I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: Try expanding the parentheses and rearranging

Answer (score 1):

You need $ax + by + cz = d$ and we'll do exactly that. Expand your expression, to have

$$z - 8(x-6) = 2(3-y) = z - 8x + 48 = 6 - 2y.$$

This implies

$$-8x + 2y + z = -42.$$

So we have $a = -8, b= 2, c= 1$ and $d= -42$. You can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$z-8(x-6)=2(3-y) \iff$$

$$z-8x+48=6-2y\;\iff$$

$$z-8x+2y=6-48 \;\iff$$

$$-8x+2y+z=-42$$

What is the normal vector ?